# FTP doesn't overwrite - put Permission denied

Tags: permissions, scripting, ftp

I have a script on a unix box which generate a log and send to a windows server.

My script has to run 4 times a day and it will append the result of each run on the same log, it means that the log on the windows server should be overwritten every time. After the first run it doesn't work and I get a

```
Permission denied
```

Which I guess that is because the file exists already on the windows server, all the rest of the script works fine and I have all the history in my log on the unix side.

The syntax of my script for the FTP is:

```
ftp -n $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWD
binary
prompt
lcd /dba/logs/
mput monitor_FM2.log
quit
EOF
exit 0
```

I tried also with `put` instead of `mput`, but the result is the same.

Comment: Does the owner on the file match the ftp user name?

Comment: @RamanSailopal sorry, i found out what the issue was. Below what i did. Thanks anyway for your interest

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the problem. Basically the user I use to connect from unix to windows didn't have the right permissions on the windows folder, that's why my error. I gave it the permission it needs and now works fine.